# getResource will always return null

Tags: java

This is driving me crazy. I have a simple eclipse project with a src folder and a class in it. But I can't seem to get getResource to find it. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.net.URL;

public class ContextTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = ContextTest.class.getResource("/src/ContextTest.java");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

If I right-click on the class name, the path is `/TestsProject/src/ContextTest.java` and the default classpath according to the Classpath tab in Run Configurations is `TestProject`.

It doesn't work with `/bin/ContextTest.java` , `/ContextTest.java` , `ContextTest.java` either.

Comment: This looks like you're using Eclipse.  Resources you want included in your jar should be stored in the resources folder.  This way you should be able to access them without the `src` path prefix

Comment: Yes, it is Eclipse. But I don't even have a resources folder, just src and bin. Is getResources IDE-dependent?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eclipse (just this problem).  I believe you need to create the folder yourself.  As to how Eclipse knows about, I'm afraid is beyond my knowledge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load resources using `ContextTest.class.getResource("/....")` the leading `/` is translated as an absolute path. Here absolute means from your *root package* (i.e. the *default* package).

In Eclipse the root package is considered the one that is under the `src` folder. Your compiled classes will be placed under `bin` folder and if you create a jar you will see that your root package is not the `src` or `bin` folders but whatever folders are inside it. (for example `com`).

So the correct way to load a resource using a class absolute path would be `ContextTest.class.getResource("/ContextTest.java");`. If the file `ContextTest.java` is in the root package of *wherever your compiled classes are*, then it will be found and returned.

I hope this clears the picture.

**Update:** From the comments below it is not clear what you are trying to do. When you use `getResource()` *you are not loading a file* but *a resource from the classpath*. This would correctly find the resource even if your files were inside a jar file. So for your above example to work the file you are trying to load as a resource should be in the classpath (i.e. under `bin` folder since this is the root of your classpath when you execute from inside Eclipse). If you are trying to load a file outside of your classpath then don't try to load a resource, you could use `File` instead.

Comment: Yes, it helps clearing the picture, but still can't make it work. It must be something tricky about the way Eclipse handles it.

Comment: @LuisSep Nothing tricky. I assume you are running it from Eclipse not a jar. In that case is `ContextTest.java` under your `bin` folder? If not it won't be found

Comment: No, it is under src. But if I have to copy it to bin, then the whole point of having a src folder is lost.

Comment: @LuisSep check the update in my answer. It seems that the difference between a _resource_ and a _file_ is not clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Resources accessed via `getResource()` must be on the classpath.  Your Java files will be compiled and placed on the classpath. The compiled `.java` file will be given an extension of `.class`.

Try

```
 URL url = ContextTest.class.getResource("ContextTest.class");
```

Comment: It does find ContextTest.class, but what do you mean by an extension of .class? Is it anyhow accessible?

Comment: I'm talking about the file extension.